# Xcode + OSX upgrade issue

Tags: xcode, macos, dyld

ALL,

I hope someone here knows something about OSX and Xcode..

I have and had for a long time a Mac laptop with OSX 10.8. I did install the latest available Xcode for this version and was developing my program on it.

The compilation/linking process was working and I was able to successfully start the program from inside Xcode. And of course I was able to do debugging there.

Recently I bought myself a newer Mac laptop. I did install newer Xcode on it and since my program is located on GitHub cloned my repository there and tried to compile and run.

While compilation and linking were successful, executing failed, even before it even started (the failure was somewhere inside the Assembly code).

All libraries I'm using had been compiled with the same set of options. And compilation of my software was successful.

How do I find where/how to fix the issue?

I'm sure something inside Xcode changed which made the code generation fail. But how do I find what exactly?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I just tried to run the program from the Terminal. Here is the output from the crash:

```
Process:               dbhandler [11125]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
Identifier:            abc.dbhandler
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           dbhandler [11125]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-03-31 15:58:19.681 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        AB9F6124-7868-5E43-BBB7-1A7D8A2DEF30

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2F231255-E0CA-47D4-8FD1-08C6F47A0627

Time Awake Since Boot: 58000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       350 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/liblibdbwindow.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
  Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
       0x109ff9000 -        0x10a02bff7 +abc.dbhandler (1.0 - 1) <F1A3B876-188B-3BCD-839F-D586CC3F400A> /Users/USER/*/dbhandler.app/Contents/MacOS/dbhandler
       0x10a071000 -        0x10a113ff7 +libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <FCF4309C-08BD-3559-8E0F-47851DED7DE5> /Users/USER/*/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10a1e1000 -        0x10a27cfff +libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <B24F932F-CA10-3FDF-8159-8E94046BA19D> /Users/USER/*/libwx_osx_cocoau_html-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10a357000 -        0x10a378ff7 +libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <F5CE0D9C-260C-3362-88CC-AE3D8D9F3119> /Users/USER/*/libwx_osx_cocoau_qa-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10a3ad000 -        0x10a4d8fff +libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <2AF1A22E-8DC9-30C3-898E-7BE762476889> /Users/USER/*/libwx_osx_cocoau_adv-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10a6c3000 -        0x10abb9ff7 +libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <4EEDAE00-B05C-3D05-8488-7EC8F8F7A824> /Users/USER/*/libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10b0ad000 -        0x10b0c0fff +libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <7CB5A2DA-A81D-3352-AE8D-D23ACBBC426D> /Users/USER/*/libwx_baseu_xml-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10b0d7000 -        0x10b10cfff +libwx_baseu_net-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <F758CDB6-A8A3-32A9-95D2-2155EBEB183B> /Users/USER/*/libwx_baseu_net-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10b159000 -        0x10b348ff7 +libwx_baseu-3.1.1.0.0.dylib (0) <34B6DA7C-F404-3B1C-8EC9-F5FD781F0629> /Users/USER/*/libwx_baseu-3.1.1.0.0.dylib
       0x10c57c000 -        0x10c5c6acf  dyld (551.4) <8A72DE9C-A136-3506-AA02-4BA2B82DCAF3> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff51f5f000 -     0x7fff521edff7  com.apple.audio.toolbox.AudioToolbox (1.14 - 1.14) <E0B8B5D8-80A0-308B-ABD6-F8612102B5D8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
    0x7fff528c1000 -     0x7fff528c1fff  com.apple.Carbon (158 - 158) <F8B370D9-2103-3276-821D-ACC756167F86> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
    0x7fff52dd3000 -     0x7fff52dd3fff  com.apple.Cocoa (6.11 - 22) <78E6C28E-4308-3D10-AD14-0CBCF6789B3F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    0x7fff55dc4000 -     0x7fff55e5ffff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1445.71.1) <2EA4F383-CAA9-3AF0-99C5-90C22ADAA6B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff5db0d000 -     0x7fff5db1cff3  com.apple.opengl (16.7.4 - 16.7.4) <9BDE8FF9-5418-3C70-8D1C-09656884CE48> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff7916b000 -     0x7fff7916cffb  libSystem.B.dylib (1252.50.4) <CD555F3B-FDDB-35E5-A2FB-FBBF3D62031A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Model: MacBookAir7,2, BootROM MBA71.0178.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.8 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.27f2
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000, Intel HD Graphics 6000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3130
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C3531324D3332443250462D3130
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x117), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.31.1a9)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f10, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0128G, 121.33 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc., 27.2
```

The error said the the library can't be found.

This library is coming from my projectand it is written by me. But I don't see a way in the Xcode to install the project.

On top of that everything on the old Mac works out of the box.

Does this an indication of 32/64-bit incompatibility?

[/EDIT]

Comment: Maybe it's a 32/64 bit issue, edit the question and describe the error(s) you get?

Comment: @vadian, please see my edit.

Answer (score -1):

Something that might help is:

- do you get some message on the output / issue navigator?
- what type of program are you writing?
- since this was a new install, did you also installed the command line tools?
- if it is an iOS program do you have the right components?

Comment: it is not an IOS app - regular desktop Cocoa-based application. The command-line tools were installed. For the 1 - do you mean during compilation?